# How can you register a converter to convert between a String and a List of specific types in Spring Web MVC?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, converters

Our app accepts a JSON-based string in a controller method that we'd like to convert using Spring's Converter interface into a List of our specific classes.

The string is a part of a larger form submission containing additional parameters that are sent at various times.

Unfortunately it looks like Spring is picking up this converter (declared as `<String, List<Proprietary>>`) and using it to convert all Strings into Lists, which is not what is desired.

Is there any way around this using the conversion service provided by Spring MVC?  We've worked around this by just accepting the string in the controller method and performing the conversion directly, but that's not as clean.

Comment: Does Json string come in as a request parameter or is it the entire request body, if it is the entire request body, isn't @RequestBody with MessageConverters more appropriate for your situation?

Comment: Question body edited to address your question.  It's not the entire request body.

Answer (score 2):

One workaround that I can recommend is to create your own [HandlerMethodArgumentResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/support/HandlerMethodArgumentResolver.html) and trigger this HandlerMethodArgumentResolver to execute for specific arguments - say by creating an annotation called JsonArgument, annotating these arguments with @JsonArgument -

```
    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter methodParameter) {
        if (methodParameter.getParameterAnnotation(JsonArgument.class)!=null) return true;
```

Now, in this HandlerMethodArgumentResolver you can take in the specific request parameter value(Json string say) and convert it to the required type.

```
@Override
public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter, ModelAndViewContainer mav, NativeWebRequest webRequest, WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {
...
       jsonString = webRequest.getParameter(parameterName);
       Class<?> type = methodParameter.getParameterType();
       //Convert jsonString to object of appropriate type..
```

This way your change will be highly focused on only the types which you have annotated.